# Html tags hidden attributes

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a problem that all people have when they do html on different browsers. It doesn't render as expected in all browsers.

I notice that it will render the same in all browsers if you specified some of the attributes. Some browsers adjust attributes of the elements, but other don't.
So, my question is

Is there any tool that will give you all element attributes, which I don't specified in css ?
This way, I won't depend on browser render algorithms I will just see in what browsers in best render and copy attributes in css :)
Thx in advance

Comment: Do you mean CSS properties? Attribute is an HTML concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Chrome's Web Inspector (Right click, inspect element). Then go expand the Computed Style accordion. You'll see whatever is being applied to the element.
Same is the case with Firefox (Firebug) or Opera (Dragonfly) or IE (F12 Dev. Tools)

---

Apart from this, I strongly suggest you to use a reset stylesheet such as "Normalize.css" to override the browser applied styles on elements, so that they look more or less the same in all browsers.

Also, some elements such as Buttons WILL not look the same on Firefox and Chrome **by Default**. You'll need CSS to make them look the same across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have their own default styles (e.g. margins, padding and fonts) for certain elements and they can vary from browser to browser.

You can see what styles are applied to an element by using the Element Inspector of Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug (both F12). Relying on default styles is not a good idea because they could change in new versions of the browser. It is better to override them with your own CSS.

Another option is to use a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) which aims to remove all default browser styles to reduce inconsistencies across different browsers.

Example reset:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```